# CRM Javascript, multiple independent sets of script on the same OnLoad form

Tags: javascript, syntax, crm

I am new to Javascript, I basically have a form to edit on CRM. I have two pieces of script, independent of each other, they both work fine on their own when I use the OnLoad feature, however when I put both sets of code into the same script developer (since its for the same form on CRM), one of them does not work.

Can anyone help and is there any special syntax to have multiple scripts on the same form?

Thanks
The Javascript is below:

```
var _roles = 'Compliance'; //array of security roles name

var _fields = 'new_pend'; // array of field schema names to enable 

UpdateFields();

/* Functions */

function UpdateFields() {

    var oXml = GetCurrentUserRoles();

    if (oXml != null) {

        var roles = oXml.selectNodes("//BusinessEntity/q1:name");

        if (roles != null) {

            for (i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {

                for (j = 0; j < _roles.length; j++) {

                    if (roles[i].text == _roles[j]) {

                        for (k = 0; k < _fields.length; k++) {

                            try {

                                document.getElementById(_fields[k]).Disabled = false;

                            } catch (e) {

                            }

                        }

                        return;   

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    return;

}

function GetCurrentUserRoles() {

    var xml = "" +

"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +

"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +

GenerateAuthenticationHeader() +

" <soap:Body>" +

" <RetrieveMultiple xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">" +

" <query xmlns:q1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query\" xsi:type=\"q1:QueryExpression\">" +
" <q1:EntityName>role</q1:EntityName>" +
" <q1:ColumnSet xsi:type=\"q1:ColumnSet\">" +
" <q1:Attributes>" +
" <q1:Attribute>name</q1:Attribute>" +
" </q1:Attributes>" +
" </q1:ColumnSet>" + 
" <q1:Distinct>false</q1:Distinct>" +
" <q1:LinkEntities>" +
" <q1:LinkEntity>" +
" <q1:LinkFromAttributeName>roleid</q1:LinkFromAttributeName>" +
" <q1:LinkFromEntityName>role</q1:LinkFromEntityName>" +
" <q1:LinkToEntityName>systemuserroles</q1:LinkToEntityName>" +
" <q1:LinkToAttributeName>roleid</q1:LinkToAttributeName>" +
" <q1:JoinOperator>Inner</q1:JoinOperator>" +
" <q1:LinkEntities>" +
" <q1:LinkEntity>" +
" <q1:LinkFromAttributeName>systemuserid</q1:LinkFromAttributeName>" + 
" <q1:LinkFromEntityName>systemuserroles</q1:LinkFromEntityName>" +
" <q1:LinkToEntityName>systemuser</q1:LinkToEntityName>" +
" <q1:LinkToAttributeName>systemuserid</q1:LinkToAttributeName>" + 
" <q1:JoinOperator>Inner</q1:JoinOperator>" + 
" <q1:LinkCriteria>" +
" <q1:FilterOperator>And</q1:FilterOperator>" +
" <q1:Conditions>" + 
" <q1:Condition>" +  
" <q1:AttributeName>systemuserid</q1:AttributeName>" + 
" <q1:Operator>EqualUserId</q1:Operator>" +
" </q1:Condition>" +
" </q1:Conditions>" +
" </q1:LinkCriteria>" +
" </q1:LinkEntity>" + 
" </q1:LinkEntities>" +   
" </q1:LinkEntity>" +  
" </q1:LinkEntities>" +  
" </query>" +    
" </RetrieveMultiple>" +    
" </soap:Body>" +   
"</soap:Envelope>" +   
"";

    var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

    xmlHttpRequest.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);

    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", " http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/RetrieveMultiple");

    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);

    xmlHttpRequest.send(xml);

    var resultXml = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;

    return (resultXml);

}
```

Comment: Which version of CRM are you running?  Can you post the details of your scripts and how you have configured them to be called by the OnLoad event?

Comment: Hi I am running CRM 4.0 and I have uploaded the script above. The script basically calls on an OnLoad event for a form in CRM. I have defined a certain user role, and a certain field that must be enabled when the user has roles meeting the specified criteria. I am not sure if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone who has read this, I found a solution to the problem.

I used an If statement to define what the output should be based on an input into the function. This is shown in the code below, Use this code with the function GetCurrentUserRoles. Thanks for all the help.

```
if(UserHasRole("Collections") ==true)
{
crmForm.all.new_pend.Disabled = false;
return;
}
else if (UserHasRole("Collections") ==false)
{
crmForm.all.new_pend.Disabled = true;
return;
}

function UserHasRole(roleName)
{
//get Current User Roles, oXml is an object
var oXml = GetCurrentUserRoles();
if(oXml != null)

{
//select the node text
var roles = oXml.selectNodes("//BusinessEntity/q1:name");
if(roles != null)
{
 for( i = 0; i < roles.length; i++)
{
 if(roles[i].text == roleName)
{
 //return true if user has this role
 return true;
 }
}
}
}
//otherwise return false
return false;
}
```